# Why Iterations with lower index is not performed?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel.foreach

The code successfully build no compilation error however nothing iteration on runtime. I `Stopped` the `loop iteration` at 200 so loop will not proceed further but loop does not execute iteration lower than `< 200`.

I am not sure. ***Is there anything alternative of Stop I can use to fix this code?***
 Why Iterations with lower index is not performed?

How to fix this issue. I googled stuff but all vain. 
Please consider the following code.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var values= Enumerable.Range(0, 500).ToArray();
        ParallelLoopResult result = Parallel.For(0, values.Count(),
            (int i, ParallelLoopState loopState) => {
                if (i == 200)
                    loopState.Stop();
                WorkOnItem(values[i]);
            });

        Console.WriteLine(result);

    }
static void WorkOnItem(object value) {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Started working on: " + value);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Finished working on: " + value); }
```

***Any help to solve this issue would be appreciated. Thanks***

Comment: You forgot to to add your Code :)

Comment: It's hard to say without see your code and know what the problem exactly is! Which elements are you iterating over? what is the expected output? How do you iterate?

Comment: I voted to reopen because the OP has now added the missing code.

Comment: _" Is there anything alternative of Stop I can use to fix this code?"_ don't iterate to `values.Count()` and stop, iterate to `Math.Min(200, values.Count()` and drop the stop.

Comment: What do you mean by `but loop does not execute iteration lower than < 200.`? When I try your code I can see output like `Started working on 1 ... Finished working on 1`.

Comment: my tutor said. If Stop is used to stop the loop it might be happens that iterations with an index lower than 200 will not be performed. So, what is alternative to solve the issue?. We supposed not use Stop instead.

Comment: ^^ I did an example of what I meant above: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z1OFUc

Comment: I don't see why your tutor would say that. From my understanding it's plain wrong. Did you actually _see_ that behavior?

Comment: Executing your code here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oUyMQ7 absolutely shows indices < 200 executed. Did he specify what circumstances would cause that behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `loopState.Break()` instead of `loopState.Stop()`.

From the documentation of [`ParallelLoopState.Break`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.break#remarks) method:

> Break indicates that no iterations after the current iteration should be run. It effectively cancels any additional iterations of the loop. However, it does not stop any iterations that have already begun execution. For example, if Break is called from the 100th iteration of a parallel loop iterating from 0 to 1,000, all iterations less than 100 should still be run, but the iterations from 101 through to 1000 that have not yet started are not executed.